# Change color of line plotted with Tools>Basic fitting

Tags: matlab, plot

I have several different data series that i would like to do a shape-preserving curve fit on.
I have the points plotted but when i go into Tools>Basic fitting>Shape-preserving interpolant the curve gets a random(?) colour and when i go to the next series the fit disapears.

How do make the fits stay for each data serie and how do change its colour afterwards using the toolbox in the plot window. If there is no easy solution is it possible with script, what to write?

This is what one data series looks like

```
%950
Wloss_950=950/(PWM1_1250CoreLoss+PWM4_1250CoreLoss)*(885.7312-632.7188)+632.7188;
Wloss_950=[Wloss_950;950/(PWM2_2000CoreLoss+PWM4_2000CoreLoss)*(405.8198-281.4403)+281.4403];
Wloss_950=[Wloss_950;950/(PWM3_2500CoreLoss+PWM5_2500CoreLoss)*(107-24.5466)+24.5466];
Wloss_950=[Wloss_950;950/(PWM3_4000CoreLoss)*24.5466];
Wloss_950=[Wloss_950;950/(PWM3_5000CoreLoss)*20.5796];

plot(speed, Wloss_950,'+','color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the figure window go to Tools -> Edit Plot then double tap on the line and editor window should open, in which you will be able to change colour, width, etc.